# QT Multithreading - calling function from within thread in mainwindow.cpp

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to get a thread to call function `testing()` in `mainwindow.cpp` ever X amount of seconds.

I have implemented a class called `AutoSaveThread`.

The header file looks like this:

```cpp
#ifndef AUTOSAVETHREAD_H
#define AUTOSAVETHREAD_H

#include <QtCore>

#include <unistd.h>

class AutoSaveThread : public QThread
{
public:
    AutoSaveThread(QObject*);
    void run();

signals:
    void callTest();


};

#endif // AUTOSAVETHREAD_H
```

And the .cpp method looks like file looks like this:

```cpp
#include "autosavethread.h"

AutoSaveThread::AutoSaveThread(QObject *parent){
    connect(this, SIGNAL(callTest()), parent, SLOT(testing()));
}

void AutoSaveThread::run()
{
    while(true){
        sleep(3);
        emit callTest();
        // call autosave in mainwindow.cpp
    }
}
```

main.cpp is where I am creating my threads like so:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    AutoSaveThread myThread(&w);
    myThread.start();
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

The test function is:

```cpp
void MainWindow::testing()
{
    qDebug()<<"nice";
}
```

When I try run this code I get the following output:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "AutoSaveThread::callTest()", referenced from:
      AutoSaveThread::run() in autosavethread.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

After making the changes @Jens suggested I get the following error:

```
  "AutoSaveThread::callTest()", referenced from:
      AutoSaveThread::run() in autosavethread.o
  "vtable for AutoSaveThread", referenced from:
      AutoSaveThread::AutoSaveThread(QObject*) in autosavethread.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Comment: By using `emit callTest()` you're treating `callTest` as a signal.  Is that what you're trying to achieve?  If that's the case you need to declare it as a signal and use moc to generate the associated code.  Having said that you'd probably be far better of just using a [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html).

Comment: Are you sure you declare `MainWindow::testing` as slot? Is your declaration `public slots: void testing();` inside 'MainWindow'?

Comment: @SerhiyKulish yes I have

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run a handler in Qt each X seconds then you don't need to create a thread at all. Just instantiate a [`QTimer`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html), set the desired interval with [`QTimer::setInterval()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#interval-prop), and connect the `QTimer::timeout` signal to the slot/handler you want to run.

For a working example, check the [details section on `QTimer`'s doc page](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#details).

Comment: As part of my coursework specifications, I must use threads to automatically save the file being worked on.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: You are not running the program, you are trying to compile it and what you get is a build error: you are missing the implementation of callTest().

For using signals and slots, the header of autosavethread.h has to be compiled with the moc-compiler. This will generate the missing methods.

The moc-generated files have to be compiled and linked with the rest of your sources.

For this to work, your class has to be equipped with the key-word Q_OBJECT:

```
class AutoSaveThread : public QThread
{
   Q_OBJECT
public:
```

Recommendation: Use Qt Creator and start with a simple sample. Then progress to using threads. Threading will make things far more obscure for you - especially if you start your thread before starting your main program, you might run into all kinds of issues.

Comment: Hi there @Jens. Thank for for your help. I have made the changes you suggested so far, and now get a new error - I have edited my question displaying it. Any further help would be greatly appreciated!